# Bound on the difference of two functions

Tags: calculus, inequality

Is it possible to bound the following difference

$$
\sin\left(\frac{tx_2}{2}\right)\cos(f(t)-tx_2)-\sin\left(\frac{tx_1}{2}\right)\cos(f(t)-tx_1)
$$

by $(tx_2-tx_1)$ (assuming that $x_2>x_1\ge0$ and $t\ge 0$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\sin\left(\frac{tx_2}{2}\right)\cos(f(t)-tx_2)-\sin\left(\frac{tx_1}{2}\right)\cos(f(t)-tx_1) |= |(\sin\left(\frac{tx_2}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{tx_1}{2}\right))\cos(f(t)-tx_2) + \sin\left(\frac{tx_1}{2}\right)(\cos(f(t)-tx_2) - \cos(f(t)-tx_1))| \le |\sin\left(\frac{tx_2}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{tx_1}{2}\right)| + |\cos(f(t)-tx_2) - \cos(f(t)-tx_1)| \le \frac{t}{2}|x_2 -x_1| + t |x _2 - x_1| = \frac{3t}{2}|x_2 - x_1|$$